# Getting a substring from a string (characters in between single quotes) (Python)

Tags: python, regex

This is the string I currently have:

```
URL = "location.href='agent_specific_listing.php?sid=131184&mls=693010&a=103&site_id=540&page_current=1';"
```

I am trying to split the substring by single quotes so that this is the result:

```
new_url = 'agent_specific_listing.php?sid=131184&mls=693010&a=103&site_id=540&page_current=1'
```

I tried to use re and findall but I got empty string back:

```
print(re.findall(r"\(u'(.*?)',\)", URL)) // printed empty lists
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong. Many thanks.

Comment: you can try `re.findall(r"'(.*)'", URL)`

Comment: And [another non-regex option](http://ideone.com/eewOF9). Will you always have just 1 substring inside the single apostrophes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print re.findall(r"\'(.*?)\'", URL)
```

because this is how you address a single quote:

```
\'   matches a literal '
```

Comment: You do not need to escape the single apostrophe since you use `"` to delimit the string literal. You'd better describe the lazy matching used in the regex and that it always comes with performance cost.

Comment: @stribizhev yes that is true, the double quotation was just by habit.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> print(re.findall(ur"'(.*?)'", URL))
['agent_specific_listing.php?sid=131184&mls=693010&a=103&site_id=540&page_current=1']
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

```
URL = "location.href='agent_specific_listing.php?sid=131184&mls=693010&a=103&site_id=540&page_current=1';"


newURL = URL.split('location.href=')[1]

print(newURL)
```

Output:

```
'agent_specific_listing.php?sid=131184&mls=693010&a=103&site_id=540&page_current=1';
```